# Relevant Singularities.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

So, I'm working on the following problem.

> Compute $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4 +4}dx $

I've chosen the following contours: $$ C_1: z(t)=Rt, \ -1 \le t \le 1 \\ C_2: z(\theta)=Re^{i\theta}, \ 0\ \le \theta \le \pi \\ C=C_1 \, + \, C_2 $$

Now, to find the singularities.

$$ x^4+4=0 \Rightarrow x=\sqrt[4]{-4}=\sqrt[4]{4e^\pi}=\sqrt2 \sqrt[4]{e^\pi}=\sqrt2 \, \exp[i(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{2\pi k}{4})] \, \, \text{for} \, \, k=0,1,2,3 $$

Let $ z_1=\sqrt2 e^{\pi i/4}, \ z_2= \sqrt2 e^{3\pi i/4}, \ z_3=\sqrt2 e^{-3\pi i/4}, \ z_4=\sqrt2 e^{-\pi i/4}  $

So, my question is regarding the choice for which singularity to choose in the CIF. I understand that $z_3$ and $z_4$ are outside of the contour and therefore irrelevant. But now I'm left with $z_1$ and $z_2$. In my professor's solution to this problem, he says

> Notice that for $R >\sqrt2$, $C$ may be deformed into a contour which is positively oriented and contains a small circle around one relevant singularity, $1 +i$, which I’ll call $C_3$, the other singularity $−1 +i$, which I’ll call $C_4$, the line connecting them $C_5$ and $−C_5$ to close the contour.

I don't really follow his logic here, why is $z_1$ the only relevant singularity when $z_2$ is also on the same line? Could someone please elaborate on this?

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't say "the only". It says "one relevant". Perhaps it would be clearer if it said "one of the relevant ... the other relevant".

Comment: @Chappers Hmmm, thank you for pointing that out. If I'm understanding correctly, I can use either singularity when integrating?

Comment: You're parsing it wrongly. You use both singularities. The contour the professor talks about consists of two circles, $C_3$ and $C_4$, each around one of the singularities, and a connection between those circles.

Comment: You need both, since both are inside the contour. The answer is showing that the contour can be deformed so that you only have to look at one at a time.

Comment: Oh, I remember him talking about this now. I think I understand. In my professor's solution, $C_5$ and $-C_5$ describe the line connecting the two singularities. This should end up being zero, leaving you with the integration of the contours surrounding the two singularities, correct?

Comment: Note that choosing $a,b$ correctly $f(z) = \frac{z}{z^4+4}-\frac{a}{z-z_1}-\frac{b}{z-z_2}$ is analytic on $\Re(z) \ge 0$ so that $\int_C f(z)dz = 0$ and $\int_C \frac{1}{z-z_1}dz = 2i\pi$.